# Easiest way to share screen with students without using internet

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I am teaching basic programming skills to a group of 8 students in High School. It is becoming increasingly irritating to have to constantly write down syntax in a white board rather than just show the students on my laptop screen.

Other than using a projector, is there a (inexpensive) way I can show the students what's happening on my screen without using internet. The students sit close to me, so using cables is a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your case it looks like your goal is to share code syntax etc

***A workaround*** 
Instead of screen sharing i am suggesting a shared folder where you share files

- create a shared network drive or folder and store files
- make it read only and give access to everybody if not worried about sharing
- your students can just look at those files

***Assumptions***
that you have some kind of network, and your students can ping your IP and vice versa

***Detailed Steps***
If you all are on the same network, Then

Sharing
 - create a folder on your computer
 - Right click > Properties > Sharing > Share.. > Everyone ( Permission Level Read)

Testing

- Try first from your computer itself just open Windows explorer and go to \your_ip_address\
- you should see the shared folder here
- Now try from a student's computer same process as shown above

***If you do not have a network***
Create an ad-hoc wireless network and have your students join it.
[Set up a computer-to-computer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: How do they do that exactly assume the author does not know how

Answer (score 0):

There are various options if your laptop is connected to the students' by a network, but I'm assuming that by "without using internet" you mean no networking at all.

The simplest answer would then be to plug the largest monitor or digital TV you can find into your laptop, point it at the students, then duplicate your laptop's display onto it. The monitor needs to have a cable that matches the output of your laptop (VGA, HDMI, etc.) If you need several screens so that all the students can see, you may be able to buy a splitter cable that will let the laptop drive several monitors at the same time (google "VGA splitter" or "HDMI splitter").

Getting the same picture to display on all the monitors should be fairly easy, but the precise instructions depend on which version of windows you are using.  Here are some [instructions for Windows 10](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/51201/use-dual-monitors-with-windows-10/), but google for "duplicate display" and your windows version if you're using something else.